# Вопрос о корректности переноса ответов

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, слияние-вопросов

Здравствуйте!

30 августа было выполнено слияние вопроса «[Ссылка на суперкласс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560963/%D0%A1%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81)» в «[Получение ссылки на экземпляр суперкласса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560889/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)» с полным переносом всех ответов.

Вопрос: зачем был выполнен этот перенос? Ведь эти два вопроса имеют несколько различную формулировку и освещаемые нюансы (*вызов конструктора и методов* против *неявное преобразование this*). Да, в целом они спрашивают об организации наследования, однако ответы при переносе полностью утратили смысл.

И ещё: зачем собственно был выполнено само перемещение ответов? Ведь в иных случаях тема помечалась как дубликат и закрывалась в нетронутом виде.

Comment: Перемещение ответов - это один из этапов процесса слияния вопросов. Кроме них, перемещаются комментарии к вопросу.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Оба вопроса заданы одним участником, с разницей в 2 часа. Суть обоих - как получить ссылку на суперкласс, в чуть-чуть разной формулировке. В первом вопросе топикастер пытается сделать это кодом, во втором - прямо формулирует проблему.

Более того, к отмеченному топикастером ответу в первом вопросе есть [его комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560889/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0#comment729121_560912)

> Как я понимаю, в super удерживается ссылка на экземпляр суперкласса. Могу ли я каким-то образом всё же явно вернуть её из экземпляра расширенного класса?

и [ответ на него](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560889/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0#comment729154_560912), c 8+, добавлен за 40 минут до появления вторго вопроса:

> нет, вы понимаете совершенно неправильно. super - это не переменная и не ссылка, super - это ключевое слово, которое позволяет вызвать метод суперкласса и не более того.

Сравните с формулировкой второго вопроса:

> Как я понимаю, при создании экземпляра класса B, в нём хранится ссылка на экземпляр родительского класса A.

Т.е. второй вопрос появился только потому, что

- Топикастер невнимательно прочитал ответ, который он отметил как принятый.
- Уточняющий комментарий был добавлен без упоминания участника, и он его просто не увидел.

Я добавил уточняющую формулировку из второго вопроса в первый, теперь все ответы смотрятся нормально.

Кстати, совпадение сути вопросов привело к тому, что другой участник дал на оба вопроса абсолютно одинаковые ответы, и этого почти никто не заметил :)